# Printing styled text to the terminal

Tags: terminal

I have a program that I run through the command line and I wanted to print out bold or styled text similar to how the man pages are bold (I can't think of a styled example offhand).

How do I style text sent to the terminal?

If it makes a difference, I'm running a MacOSX terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to use the [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this SO question: [Colored grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138383/colored-grep) which shows a simple way to color output for VT100 terminals (works great on MacOSX)

Answer (score 1):

Another useful SO Question is: [Apply formatting to unix shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510202/apply-formatting-to-unix-shell), with a link to [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and examples from a shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from any shell script using the `tput` program to output `terminfo` codes.  Oddly, there's a code to turn vold on but not off---you have to turn everything off.  Reverse video can be turned on and off with `tput smso` and `tput rmso`.

Here's an example for bold (`/bin/ksh`):

```
print -n "This word is "; tput bold; print -n "bold"; tput sgr0; print "!"
```

In most programming languages it is easier to fork a process and call `tput` than it is to bother with the `ncurses` library (to which `tput` is a command-line interface).